# Twitter bootstrap select menu pushing other elements below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: BEfore]

[image]

This is what is happening.Im using bootsrap-select for this select.

its css is

```
/*!
 * bootstrap-select v1.4.2
 * http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/
 *
 * Copyright 2013 bootstrap-select
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */

.bootstrap-select.btn-group,
.bootstrap-select.btn-group[class*="span"] {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.form-search .bootstrap-select.btn-group,
.form-inline .bootstrap-select.btn-group,
.form-horizontal .bootstrap-select.btn-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.bootstrap-select.form-control {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group.pull-right,
.bootstrap-select.btn-group[class*="span"].pull-right,
.row-fluid .bootstrap-select.btn-group[class*="span"].pull-right {
    float: right;
}

.input-append .bootstrap-select.btn-group {
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.input-prepend .bootstrap-select.btn-group {
    margin-right: -1px;
}

.bootstrap-select:not([class*="span"]):not([class*="col-"]):not([class*="form-control"]) {
    width: 150px;
}

.bootstrap-select {
    /*width: 220px\9; IE8 and below*/
    width: 220px\0; /*IE9 and below*/
}

.bootstrap-select.form-control:not([class*="span"]) {
    width: 100%;
}

.bootstrap-select > .btn {
    font-weight:700;border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
    width: 100%;
}

.error .bootstrap-select .btn {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48;
}


.dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 2000;
}

.bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow.open > .btn {
    z-index: 2051;
}

.bootstrap-select .btn:focus {
    outline: thin dotted #333333 !important;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color !important;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .btn .filter-option {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    right: 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .btn .caret {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 12px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group > .disabled,
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li.disabled > a {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group > .disabled:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group[class*="span"] .btn {
    width: 100%;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu.inner {
    position: static;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu dt {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    cursor: default;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .div-contain {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li {
    position: relative;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li > a.opt {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li > a {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li > dt small {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a i.check-mark {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a i.check-mark {
    display: none;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
    margin-right: 34px;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li small {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li:not(.disabled) > a:hover small,
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li:not(.disabled) > a:focus small,
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li.active:not(.disabled) > a small {
    color: #64b1d8;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li > dt small {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow .dropdown-toggle:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 9px;
    display: none;
}

.bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow .dropdown-toggle:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 10px;
    display: none;
}

.bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow.dropup .dropdown-toggle:before {
  bottom: auto;
  top: -3px;
  border-top: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow.dropup .dropdown-toggle:after {
  bottom: auto;
  top: -3px;
  border-top: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow.pull-right .dropdown-toggle:before {
    right: 12px;
    left: auto;
}
.bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow.pull-right .dropdown-toggle:after {
    right: 13px;
    left: auto;
}

.bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow.open > .dropdown-toggle:before,
.bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow.open > .dropdown-toggle:after {
    display: block;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .no-results {
    padding: 3px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.mobile-device {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    opacity: 0;
}

.bootstrap-select.fit-width {
    width: auto !important;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group.fit-width .btn .filter-option {
    position: static;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group.fit-width .btn .caret {
    position: static;
    top: auto;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.control-group.error .bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle{
    border-color: #b94a48;
}

.bootstrap-select-searchbox {
    padding: 4px 8px;
}

.bootstrap-select-searchbox input {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

js is

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn btn-white btn-sm'
  });
});
      </script>
```

Why is it streching down other elements below?why does this happen?The html is

```
 <div class="form-group">

                      <label class="control-label" style="display:inline;">Expiry</label>

               <div>                



    <select class="selectpicker" id="expiry_month" name="expiry_month">
    <option selected>Select Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>






    <select class="selectpicker" id="expiry_year" name="expiry_year">
    <option selected>Select Year</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2025">2025</option>
    <option value="2026">2026</option>                          <option value="2027">2027</option>
    <option value="2028">2028</option>
    <option value="2029">2029</option>
    <option value="2030">2030</option>
    <option value="2031">2031</option>
    <option value="2032">2032</option>
    <option value="2033">2033</option>
    <option value="2034">2034</option>
    <option value="2035">2035</option>
    <option value="2036">2036</option>
    </select>





    </div>
    </div>
```

Is it the problem with its css?Or can I use any specifications in the javascript?Im using this  http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: The problem is that,it has got a whole bunch of javascripts and css,that I wont be able to putthall in jsfiddle.Other wise I would have done.By just seeing the images,what can be the issue.Any guess?

Comment: Try to wrap each select with a div with class say `span3` (depending on the width change the span class)

Answer (score 1):

It is both css and javascript issue. why you won't try to use Select2 http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ ? where it doesn't have any issues. I'm using it since long time.

Comment: If you wanted to use bootstrap-select itself, can you please make a playground such as jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net where it has issues.

Answer (score 0):

use Bootstrap Grid System. That helps me in the past.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
   <label class="control-label" style="display:inline;">Expiry</label>
    <div clas="row"> 
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 clearfix">
   <select class="selectpicker" id="expiry_month" name="expiry_month">
    <option selected>Select Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 clearfix">
    <select class="selectpicker" id="expiry_year" name="expiry_year">
    <option>Select Year</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2025">2025</option>
    <option value="2026">2026</option>
    <option value="2027">2027</option>
    <option value="2028">2028</option>
    <option value="2029">2029</option>
    <option value="2030">2030</option>
    <option value="2031">2031</option>
    <option value="2032">2032</option>
    <option value="2033">2033</option>
    <option value="2034">2034</option>
    <option value="2035">2035</option>
    <option value="2036">2036</option>
    </select>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn btn-warning btn-xs'
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ck7qD/1/)

Comment: he is not talking about issues in grid. the bootstrap-select plugin is expanding dropdowns might because of position issue!

Comment: You shoudn't vote me down it is posibile to be true. please take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/ck7qD/1/

Comment: I updated the code. Works for me. But, as you said, better user select2 plugin. Depends of what he need.

Answer (score 0):

Is this bug with bootstrap
   [JsFidle][1]

```
     [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/Mur7J/
```